# Android Android Studio problems

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After I had emergency reboot my computer I have problems with imports from `JDK` and `SDK` for all my projects even new. `Android Studio` doesn't see any imports except `Gradle` libs and `R.class`. Moreover, it does not see packages which I were created. I clean project, rebuild it but nothing has changed.[image] Maybe someone had something similar?

Answer (score 1):

In the File menu, you should see an option for "Invalidate caches and restart". Select it and allow the application to restart.

This will clear any corrupted symbol caches and allow them to be rebuilt.

You may need to rebuild after this step for everything to show up correctly.

Comment: Your solution fix only JDK imports. To solve SDK imports problem I change my app compile SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

Do this
File-> invalidate caches/restart

Answer (score 0):

an option for "Invalidate caches and restart". Select it
See Image :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H17pz.png]